# How to add OpenMp to triple nested for-loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

The goal is to add as much OpenMP to the following Cholesky factor function to increase parallelization. So far, I only have one `#pragma omp parallel for` implemented correctly. `vector<vector<double>>` represents a 2-D matrix. I've already tried adding `#pragma omp parallel for` for
`for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`, `for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)`, and `for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)` but the parallelization goes wrong. `makeMatrix(n, n)` initializes a `vector<vector<double>>` of all zeroes of size `nxn`.

```
vector<vector<double>> cholesky_factor(vector<vector<double>> input)
{
    int n = input.size();
    vector<vector<double>> result = makeMatrix(n, n);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)
        {
            double value = input[i][k];
            for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            {
                value -= result[i][j] * result[k][j];
            }
            result[i][k] = value / result[k][k];
        }
        double value = input[i][i];
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            value -= result[i][j] * result[i][j];
        }
        result[i][i] = std::sqrt(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: _"but the parallelization goes wrong"_ - You need to be more specific.

Comment: "Adding more OpenMP" to nested loops does only give better performance when the outer loop in itself doesn't give enough parallelism. In that case one can use the `collapse` clause, but here I don't think there is a trivial way of doing this due to different combinations `(i,j,k)` overlapping in the ares of the matrix in reading and writing. For the present parallelization of the second `j`-loop to be correct you have to add `reduction(-: value)`.

Comment: Also your inner loop bounds are dependent on the outer loop indices. Therefore you can't use `collapse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can parallelize much more than this with this algorithm, as the `i`th iteration of the outer loop depends on the results of the `i - 1`th iteration and the `k`th iteration of the inner loop depends on the results of the `k - 1`th iteration.

```cpp
vector<vector<double>> cholesky_factor(vector<vector<double>> input)
{
    int n = input.size();
    vector<vector<double>> result = makeMatrix(n, n);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; ++k)
        {
            double value = input[i][k];
            // reduction(-: value) does the same 
            // (private instances of value are initialized to zero and
            // added to the initial instance of value when the threads are joining
            #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: value)
            for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j)
            {
                value -= result[i][j] * result[k][j];
            }
            result[i][k] = value / result[k][k];
        }
        double value = input[i][i];
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: value)
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            value -= result[i][j] * result[i][j];
        }
        result[i][i] = std::sqrt(value);
    }

    return result;
}
```